# Mysql varchar comparing

Tags: php, mysql

In my mysql database there are 2 tables.
1.A
2.B

In table A columns are id(varchar)primary key,location(varchar),date(date)
In table B columns are id(varchar)foreign key,activity(varchar),cost(int)

I use search box ,in which if both tables id field matches then result displays.
when i use numbers it works OK,but when i use alphanumeric values then it not works.

So plz help me
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Going to nee way more information than that, but the first thing that comes to mind is that you're probably not quoting the strings.

Comment: Show your comparing code

Answer (score 1):

First up: using varchar as an id is probably a bad idea. If you want some sort of information stored in the locations/activities that you now store in the id-field, you might want to consider adding another field, making the id an integer and just compare integers.

That said, it should just work with the following:

```
SELECT *  
FROM A, B  
WHERE A.id = B.id AND A.fieldthatwassearched = '".$value_from_php."' ;
```

And:

```
SELECT *
FROM A, B
WHERE A.id = B.id AND A.id = '".$value_from_php."'
```

Not the '" and "' around the value, these are important, because you need to send mysql a string, so it needs to be quoted ;)

Comment: The value $value_from_php could be vulnerable for SQL injection. Use mysql_real_escape_string($value_from_php) instead or don't use PHP variables in the example.

Comment: True, this is the most basic example for a search-ish query. You should look into things like SQL injection, Martin's solution should solve most of it :)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work for you?

```
SELECT *
from A
inner join B on B.id = A.id
WHERE A.id = 'whatyoursearchingfor'
```